# How to get Xcode to generate warning (or error) on Mismatched Return Type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, type-mismatch

I just made a code change in the type for a method's return type and was counting on the compiler to show warnings which would allow me to find and fix wherever the mismatch now occurs.  But no warnings.  In my Settings I discovered that "Mismatched Return Type" was already "Yes" for all build types, so I decided to change it to "Yes (treat as error)" and did a rebuild.  Still no indication in build results.

I then changed "Treat Warnings as Errors" to "Yes" and that produced a few helpful error messages, but no mismatch warnings. Perhaps I do not understand something about the compiler and Objective-C return types, but it seems that a bool should not be acceptable when my method specifies that is should return an NSNumber*.

Here is my code:

```
+(NSNumber*) compilerCompletelyFineWithThis
{
    if ([m_session tryThis])
    {
        return [m_session goGetSumthin];
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

The docs suggest that Mismatched Return Type is associated with GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE, but it is not clear what rules this enforces.

In the pic below of the warnings section(s) of my Build Settings, notice the relevant settings. I have "Treat Warnings as Errors" and "Mismatched Return Type" turned on for all my builds.

[image]

Is there a way to get Xcode to let me know when I am violating this kind of contract between a method definition and the calling code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sad news… the problem here is not with the “Mismatched Return Type” warning/error setting.

The problem is that `false` is actually a `#define` for `0`. You can find the definition in `stdbool.h`, hidden away at this path in Xcode 8.3.3:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stdbool.h

Since it's a preprocessor define, it gets changed from `false` to `0` before the semantic analysis part of the compiler sees it.

In C, you're allowed to use a bare literal 0 as a null pointer. So in your case, `false` is treated as a null pointer to `NSNumber` and is a legal return value.

Even if you use the preferred Objective-C boolean `NO`, that alone won't fix the problem. `NO` is a `#define` for `__objc_no` (see `/usr/include/objc/objc.h`), which is [a clang extension that effectively acts as a literal 0](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) (but which allows the compiler uses to convert `@YES` and `@NO` to the proper singletons).

To get a warning, you need to take three steps:

1. Add `-Wnon-literal-null-conversion` to your “Other C Flags” build setting.
2. Return `NO` instead of `false`.
3. Declare your function to return `_Nonnull`.

Result:

```
+(NSNumber * _Nonnull) compilerCompletelyFineWithThis {
    return NO;
    // error: Expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
}
```

**Starting in Xcode 9**, you can turn on the “Implicit Non-Literal Null Conversions” build setting instead of modifying “Other C Flags”.

Comment: Gee whiz.  Where's the technology when you need it?  I have to hunt all the instances of these mismatches down now.  Thanks.